# Error generating beep using ToneGenerator class

Tags: android, beep, tone-generator

I'm new to android development

I'm working in an android app that simply changes volume and play beep "to preview current sound level"

I use `startTone` in `ToneGenerator` class to generate this beep , like this :

```
 ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 100);
 tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
```

but *sometimes* this code doesn't work and generate following exceptions

```
11-20 00:32:44.262: E/AudioTrack(4701): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
11-20 00:32:44.262: E/ToneGenerator(4701): AudioTrack->initCheck failed
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's too late now , but i am posting the answer for anyone will come later.

it was just about releasing created objects of `ToneGenerator` because rapidly creating objects of 'ToneGenerator' without releasing them will cause the application to crash.

complete code :

```
    final ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
    tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
    tg.release();
```

Comment: After adding the `tg.Release();`, I also had to restart the whole emulator (not just the app) in order to stop the app from crashing.

Comment: Also you have to re-initialize like this...
 final ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 400);