# android app crashes after several clicks on a button

Tags: android

could anyone help to solve the below problem:

I created a simple activity contains 2 buttons, every time i start clicking randomly on the buttons (even when slow clicking), the app crashes when the total clicks reach exactly 30 clicks.

Java:

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View button_1=(findViewById(R.id.button_1));
        button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING); 
                final ToneGenerator mToneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume_level * 14);
                mToneGenerator.stopTone();
                mToneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1, 100);
            }
        });

        final View button_2=(findViewById(R.id.button_2));
        button_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING); 
                final ToneGenerator mToneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume_level * 14);
                mToneGenerator.stopTone();
                mToneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_9, 100);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does logcat tell you? We need to see the error...

Comment: ....myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: kidsphone.verdoapps.com.myapplication, PID: 641
java.lang.RuntimeException: Init failed
at android.media.ToneGenerator.native_setup(Native Method)

to be cont.

Comment: at android.media.ToneGenerator.<init>(ToneGenerator.java:740)
at kidsphone.verdoapps.com.myapplication.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You shouldn't post this important information in (several) comments. Just edit your question and add it there (using code indentation)

Comment: First educated guess: You are using `new ToneGenerator` with every click. Try to instantiate the ToneGenerator outside of the click handler and then use it inside

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439051/tonegenerator-crash-android/13868360#13868360

Comment: Perfect guide.. thanks for your assist.. what i did is moving the line of creating the new ToneGenerator above and outside the onclick void

Thanks again